# AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult result is NULL randomly! after AJAX call in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api

I need an advice. I wrote an MVC app to access Google Gmail API (using Google OAuth 2 Authentication), as explained in Google's Tutorial: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

The idea is - Index action initializes

> private static AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult result;

after it performs Google OAuth2 authentication. That **result** object has **Credentials.Token** property that contains issued AccessToken and RefreshToken. Next, Index action returns a vew (rendered HTML) that has a DIV where I want to load Gmail messages asynchronously. When the page loads, there is a Javascript function that fires on page load even in a browser. Simple. That Javascript function makes an AJAX call to Gmail() action in HomeController. It makes these calls with a 1 minute interval (js timer). Since **result** object is marked as **static** it should be available to pass Credentials to Gmail API Service method that is implemented in GmailManager helper class:

> return PartialView(GmailManager.GetGmail(result.Credential));

The problem is **sometimes** the **result** object **is null** inside the Gmail() action **and the NullReferenceException is thrown**

I dont understand why this is happening if the **result** was initialized in Index action and it is **static**, so it should be alive by the time the call is made to Gmail() action. It should never be null. If it was *constantly null* I would understand and try to debug and fix it, but it is **random** and I cannot understand the logic.

If someone understands what is happening please advice.

Below is my HomeController code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult result;

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result.Credential == null) 
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken)) 
            SaveRefreshTocken(result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Gmail()
    {
        result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshToken"];
        return PartialView(GmailManager.GetGmail(result.Credential));
    }

    private static void SaveRefreshTocken(string refreshToken)
    {
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        config.AppSettings.Settings["RefreshToken"].Value = refreshToken;
        config.Save();
    }
}
```